# Unable to install emacs 26.3

Tags: build, emacs26

I am trying to install emacs 26.3. In installed

```
sudo apt install autoconf make gcc texinfo libgtk-3-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libtiff5-dev libgnutls-dev libncurses5-dev
```

It cant find `libgnutls-dev`. I skipped that and did `./configure --with-gnutls=no` and when I do `make`

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/itsy/Downloads/emacs-26.3/admin/unidata'
  CCLD     temacs
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
```

Is there something I need to install ?

Comment: Which Linux distro (and which version) do you use?

Comment: `apt build-dep emacs` should install all the required stuff for you

Comment: @rpluim I tried that. It says everything is installed.

Comment: @Philopolis I am on UBuntu 18.04

Comment: So you’re trying to build emacs 26 (ie the current version) against headers and libraries provided by your 2 year old OS. Maybe this needs a newer version of libSM or its headers? I don’t have a better idea.